# Deploy ASP.NET MVC on virtual directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, virtual-directory

When i return View() from my action, result URL was not include virtual directory name.

expect for this

```
...../MyMVCApp/Controller/Action
```

but i got this

```
..../Controller/Action
```

How can i fix this problem?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
My RouteConfig.cs is

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Con", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and on IIS(6.1) I just add application on the some root site like this

```
Website
 |
 |- MyMVCApp
 |- OtherApp
```

Comment: Can you show how you are returning view? Post a controller action code. You don't really need to use `VirtualDirectoryName` while returning view

Comment: i just 
    return View(model);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be an issue at all as long as your virtual directory is a web application in IIS. If you have configured your project as a web app and you still have issues then it should be a routing problem.

By saying that, I believe your issue is IIS configuration or a routing problem. Can you paste a screenshot of your IIS structure and how you are registering your routes?

Comment: I got it now.
I have some hardcoded "/Controller/Index/" that make thing go wrong.
Thank you.